# C#: Convert String to DBType.AnsiStringFixedLength

Tags: c#, sql

I have a stored procedure. One of its input parameters is expecting a char(8). I try to convert a string "AAA" to this particular parameter type, which is a DBType.AnsiStringFixedLength.

```
object v = Convert.ChangeType("AAA", param.DbType.GetTypeCode()); 
// param is AnsiStringFixedLength
```

However, all I get is an exception: Input string was not in a correct format.
And the stack trace says: at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) [...]

Why is System.Convert trying to convert a string into a number, even though the prodecure's parameter is expecting a char(8)? How do I solve this? I don't want to use one huge switch case mapping all SQL types to CLR types...

EDIT: 
This is the code in question: (A generic method to call any MS SQL stored procedure)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.config.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = this.config.StoredProcedureName;

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

        foreach (SqlParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            if (param.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input ||
                 param.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
            {
                try
                {
                    string rawParam = param.ParameterName.Replace("@", "");
                    if (this.config.Parameters.ContainsKey(rawParam))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            param.Value = Convert.ChangeType(this.config.Parameters[rawParam],
                                param.DbType.GetTypeCode());
                        }
                        catch(Exception oops)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not convert to '{0}'.", param.DbType), oops);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentException("parameter's not available");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The actual parameter values are provided by this.config.Parameters - all of them are strings. I iterate through SqlCommand's parameter list and set them accordingly. Converting the string values to the parameter's Sql type is necessary here, and as far as I can see, the Sql type is provided by param.DBType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mix up some things here, or I don't get what you try to do. The [`DbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) (an enumeration) inherits `Enum` and that implements `IConvertible` -> You can call `GetTypeCode()`. But - you are now calling `Enum.GetTypeCode()`, which returns the underlying type. If you didn't specify it (and `DbType` didn't) any `Enum` is backed by an `int`.

What are you trying to solve with the code anyway? Why would you *want* to change the type of a string if the parameter is a string (although with a fixed length)?

---

Looking at the question some more it seems even more odd. You have an object v (probably for value?) - what do you care about the type?

`object v1 = "Foo";`

`object v1 = 42;`

What is the difference for you? I guess you want to pass the values to something else, but - if you only reference the value as `object` you might still need to cast it.

Please update your question and explain what you really want to do, what you expect to gain.

---

Regarding the comment:

> I'm using Convert.ChangeType(object
>   value, TypeCode typeCode), so it's not
>   really converting into an Enum/int. At
>   least that's what I thought...

See above: `DbType.GetTypeCode()` is not what you want. Try it, give me the benefit of the doubt: What do you expect to get from `DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength.GetTypeCode()`? What is the actual result, if you try it?

Now to your code: You try to set the [`SqlParameter.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value.aspx) property to the "correct" type. Two things: According to the documentation you probably *want* to set the [`SqlParameter.SqlValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue.aspx), which is the value using SQL types according to the docs. [`SqlParameter.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value.aspx), on the other hand, is the value using CLR types and allows to infer both DbType and SqlValue. Sidenote, implementation detail: The [`SqlParameter.SqlValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue.aspx) setter just calls the setter of [`SqlParameter.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value.aspx) again...

I would expect that the ADO.NET stuff converts the value on its own, if at all possible. What error are you getting without jumping through this hoops?

Comment: I'm using Convert.ChangeType(object value, TypeCode typeCode), so it's not really converting into an Enum/int. At least that's what I thought...

Comment: None at all. I can't belive it. I didn't even try. It works perfectly fine without changing the type. I just had this memory from long ago when I had troulble setting SqlCommand parameters without casting objects to appropriate sql types...

In any case, thank you very much! I'll be using SqlParameter.SqlValue. I know, next time, I'll RTFM on that ;-)

Edit: Sorry, I cannot vote for your answer, have not enough reputation points :D